# generate an ssh key for all users

Tags: ssh, git, github

I want to generate a ssh key on a virtual server that will be in use for all users. 
I did created a key for myself

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "my@gamil.com"
```

but it's under my user only. 
is there a solution for this?

Comment: I cannot let this be unsaid.  You do understand having a single key, used by multiple people, reduces the overall security of the key and exposes it to more vectors for that key being harvested.

Comment: You tagged this with [tag:github]. Is the key for connecting _to_ your server or _from_ it?

Comment: Not sure what you meant, but i think the answer is from it

Answer (score 0):

You can give a copy of your private key file to other people. You can make it world-readable and put it in a directory where other people can access the file. `ssh` is perfectly happy to use a world-readable private key file.

If the key file is protected with a passphrase, you will have to give the passphrase to other users in order for them to use the key. Once they know the passphrase, they'd be able make a copy of the key file and use `ssh-keygen` to change or remove the passphrase on the copied file.

It's not normal or common to set up an ssh key that anyone can use. So there's no standard place to store them or standard way to distribute them to the other users. You'd be on your own to choose how you'd make the key available to everyone else.